# What is the correct way to quote (and cite) computer code using the Chicago style?

Tags: citation

I would like to quote from line 205 to 214 of a particular source code.

Answer (score 1):

The [Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/tools_citationguide.html) doesn't seem to touch on this topic, but here are some links to questions asked regarding source code citations in other styles:

- [Turabian](http://libanswers.library.csupomona.edu/a.php?qid=581554)
- [Harvard UoB](https://lrweb.beds.ac.uk/guides/a-guide-to-referencing/cite_computer_program)

Perhaps you can combine the information in these links to come up with an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 1):

The Chicago Manual of Style has an entire section on citing "Unpublished and Informally Published Material."

Section 14.243 on citing web sites and blogs would seem to pertain; the guidelines for citing web site content are particularly appropriate. I've noted what modifications that would pertain to citing source code:

> For original content from online sources other than the types of
>   formally published documents discussed elsewhere in this chapter,
>   include as much of the following as can be determined:
>
> - the title or a description of the page [the filename]
> - the author of the content
> - the owner or sponsor of the site
> - a URL [of the source code repository]
> - a date of revision or modification [the commit hash for Git, the version for SVN]

So a sample source code citation might be

> 1. glm/core/func_trigonometric.inl::radians, lines 36-45, Christophe Riccio, g-truc/glm, https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/0.9.5/glm/detail/func_trigonometric.inl,
>      ccb25c84c7c53ccd78e1fb2951d335638bd3e417

This refers to the `radians` function that appears in lines 36-45 of the source file cited, in the version indexed by the SHA-1 hash in the citation.